# Some isolated point symbols not rotating while rest do using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, geopackage, svg, rotate

I'm trying to rotate some svg geology structure symbols in QGIS, using point data originally from a geoJSON file which I converted to geopackage.

I used the expression `"attitude_strike"-90` to apply the proper rotation to the symbols, and it *almost* works great. About 95% of the symbols rotate as expected, but a small number of them do not rotate.

These are symbols of one data type, with the same symbol, etc.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Here are some screenshots, first showing the various unrotated symbols, then showing the attribute table for one of those symbols, which has an strike of 10.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could u maybe join a screen capture to see whether those "left aside" share a common property ... ?

Comment: If the "attitude_strike" value is 90 your expression will evaluate as 0 (so no rotation), or if "attitude_strike" is null you will get a null value. Could you check the "attitude_strike" value of non rotating symbol  and share with us ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added some screenshots showing some of the information requested. Hopefully this shines some light on the problem.

Comment: if you use a recent enough version of QGIS the bottom of the expression builder (where you have set the "attitude_strike"-90) not only show the result of the expression but let you navigate between feature, you could use that to see what value your expression return for non rotating symbol (for the one in your screenshot you should get -80). this will help to determine if the problem is an attribute value/expression problem or a display problem

Comment: I've found that if I don't use the expression builder and simply select **"Field Type: int, double string" > "attitude_strike"** the symbols are all rotated by the appropriate value. The problem arises when I use the expression builder to correct for the initial orientation of the fault symbol.